# Landscape OpenID Authentication

Tags: landscape

Currently, I have an instance of **Canonical Landscape** installed and I would like to change the authentication method to use **ADFS 2016** via **OpenID**.

However, Landscape offers these two configurations in **services.conf**:

```
openid-provider-url = https://login.ubuntu.com/
openid-logout-url = https://login.ubuntu.com/+logout
```

If I append the following url:

```
openid-provider-url = https://<my_adfs_server>/adfs/oauth2/authorize/
```

I Get the error:

```
Error in discovery: Error fetching XRDS document: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:661)>
```

Installing the ADFS certificate does not solve my problem and as there is no place for me to configure the **clientId** from ADFS OpenID.

How is it possible to integrate Landscape with ADFS via OpenID?

***PAM** is not an option, because I can't connect directly to AD.

Answer (score 0):

The landscape can be configured to use **OpenID** and works by default with UbuntuSSO. It can be configured as per
https://help.landscape.canonical.com/LDS/ReleaseNotes12.09#OpenID_support

ADFS 2016 is using "**OpenID Connect**" which is different from "OpenID" used with Landscape. Unfortunately, at this time Landscape does not support "OpenID Connect"

Here is more about the differences:
https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/44611/difference-between-oauth-openid-and-openid-connect-in-very-simple-term

Hope this will help

Answer (score 0):

And.... From release 19.10, Landscape can use OpenID-Connect (OIDC) to authenticate users. https://docs.ubuntu.com/landscape/en/onprem-auth#openid-connect-support